# Can InetSim be used with Cygwin?

Tags: linux, perl, cygwin, posix, malware

I want to use Inetsim and that too, only on windows. Can I use it with help of cygwin?
Inetsim is a linux tool for simulating internet services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this same question.

The following excerpt is the [requirements](http://www.inetsim.org/requirements.html) for INetSim:

> For using INetSim you need a system which meets the following
>   prerequisites:
>
> - POSIX compatible and System V IPC capable operating system (e.g. Linux)
> - Perl version 5.006 or more recent
> - Perl library Net::Server (available from http://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Server)
> - Perl library Net::DNS (available from http://metacpan.org/pod/Net::DNS)
> - Perl library IPC::Shareable (available from http://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Shareable)
> - Perl library Digest::SHA (available from http://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::SHA)
> - Perl library IO::Socket::SSL (available from http://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL)
> - additionally, for IP-based connection redirection (only supported on Linux platforms with kernel support for packet queueing): Perl library Perlipq (available from https://metacpan.org/release/perlipq)

While Cygwin strives to be POSIX compatible, there is the question of what System V is and whether or not it's supported. [This unhelpful message](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2005-10/msg00255.html) from the mailing list for the Cygwin project directs us to [this entry](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygserver.html) from the user guide. Reading into the post suggests that System V is for IPC shared memory and message queues. Thankfully, the following excerpt from the guide suggests that running `cygserver` will provide the necessary services for System V to function:

> - -m, --no-sharedmem
>
> Don't start XSI IPC Shared Memory support. If you don't need XSI IPC
>   Shared Memory support, you can switch it off here. Configuration file
>   option: kern.srv.sharedmem
>
> - -q, --no-msgqueues
>
> Don't start XSI IPC Message Queues. Configuration file option:
>   kern.srv.msgqueues

Cygwin version 2.844 is current as of this post, and it provides Perl 5.14.4-1, which satisfies the second requirement.

The 3rd to 7th bullets surround particular perl libraries and are left as an exercise to the reader.

The final bullet, may be the nail in the coffin, however, as I can find no evidence that Perlipq is available for Cygwin (note: this requires kernel support as well, which can easily become too big of a problem for Cygwin to bother with).

Unless something changes, I believe the answer to your question is: No, INetSim cannot be used with cygwin.